# Controller not receiving list of Model in Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to send the data from my view to controller, I created a PO, then on the next page I viewed the products to show and to select by the user. but when user select and post the data, controller didn't get that.

Here is a controller data

```
public IActionResult CreatePO()
        {
            var LastPO = _context.PurchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(p => p.PONumber).FirstOrDefault();
            int TempPO = Convert.ToInt32(LastPO.PONumber.Replace("PO", "")) + 1;
            var NewPO = "PO" + TempPO.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
            ViewBag.NewPO = NewPO;
            var UserData = _context.Users.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
            List<Vendor> vendors = _context.Vendors.Where(e => e.CreatedBy == UserData.UserId).ToList();
            ViewBag.Vendors = vendors;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreatePO(PurchaseOrder model)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var UserData = _context.Users.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
                model.CreatedBy = UserData.UserId;
                model.UpdatedBy = UserData.UserId;
                return RedirectToAction("AddProduct", new {VendorId = model.VendorId , PONumber = model.PONumber});
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddProduct(int? VendorId, string? PONumber)
        {
            if (VendorId == null || PONumber == null)
            {
                VendorId = 2;
                PONumber = "PO00002";
            }
            List<Product> products = _context.Products.Where(e => e.VendorId == VendorId && e.Stock > 0).ToList();
            var VenderData = _context.Vendors.Where(a => a.Id == VendorId).SingleOrDefault();
            ViewBag.VendorId = VenderData.VendorName;
            ViewBag.PONumber = PONumber;
            ViewBag.Products = products;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddProduct(IEnumerable<OrderProducts> ListOfOrderProducts)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is the View of Products to Add

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Products";
}

<link href="~/css/sheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/pojavascript.js"></script>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm2()">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-3">
            <h2>
                Select Products
            </h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        @if (TempData["SuccessMsg"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
                <strong>@TempData["SuccessMsg"]</strong>
            </div>
        }
        else if (TempData["ErrorMsg"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
                <strong>@TempData["ErrorMsg"]</strong>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="row m-3 mb-3">
            <label></label>
            <input id="PONumber" readonly value="@ViewBag.PONumber" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row m-3 mb-3">
            <label></label>
            <input id="VendorId" readonly value="@ViewBag.VendorId" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row m-2 mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                <label>Select Product</label>
                <select id="Products" class="form-select">
                    <option value="0">Select Product</option>
                    @{
                        var i = 1;
                    }
                    @foreach(var ProData in ViewBag.Products)
                    {
                        <option value="tr_@i">(@ProData.SKU) @ProData.ProductName</option>
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                <button onclick="AddRow()" type="button" style="margin-top:25px" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-2 mb-3">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="POTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Select
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product ID
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SKU
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Product Name
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:200px">
                            Add Item
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Total Amount
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{i = 1;}
                    @foreach (var ProData in ViewBag.Products)
                    {
                        <tr id="tr_@i">
                            <input id="PONumber_@i" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.PONumber">
                            <input id="VendorId_@i" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.VendorId">
                            <input id="CreatedDate_@i" type="hidden" value="@DateTime.Now">
                            <td>
                                <input id="Chk_products_@i" class="form-check-input" onclick="CheckRow(this, @i)" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="Pr_ID_@i" type="text" class="form-control" value="@ProData.ProductId">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="Pr_Name_@i" type="text" class="form-control" value="@ProData.ProductName">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="SKU_@i" type="text" class="form-control" value="@ProData.SKU">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="qty">
                                    <button onclick="AddSub(@i ,0)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:5px">-</button>
                                    <input id="count_@i" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;display:inline-block;" name="qty_@i" value="1">
                                    <button onclick="AddSub(@i ,1)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:5px">+</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="UnitPrice_@i" type="number" class="form-control" value="@ProData.UnitOfPrice">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="TAmount_@i" type="number" class="form-control" value="@ProData.UnitOfPrice">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:60%;margin-top:30px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Total No of Items</th>
                    <td>
                        <input readonly type="text" id="TotItems" class="form-control" value="0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Total No of Products</th>
                    <td>
                        <input readonly type="text" id="TotProducts" class="form-control" value="0" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Total Bill</th>
                    <td>
                        <input readonly type="text" id="TotAmount" class="form-control" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Remaining Amount</th>
                    <td>
                        <input  readonly type="text" id="RemAmount" class="form-control" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="row m-2 mb-3">
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <h4 style="display:inline;">Enter amount to pay</h4>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width:50%">
                        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                            <input id="TotPaid" type="text" value="0.00" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="AjaxFormData()" class="btn btn-primary ms-lg-3" type="button" style="width:100px; margin-top:20px">
            Create
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript Ajax Call Function

```
function AjaxFormData() {
    var ListOfOrderProducts = new Array();
    var table = document.getElementById('POTable');
    if (table.rows.length != 0) {
        for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            CheckBoxVal = document.getElementById("Chk_products_" + i);
            if (CheckBoxVal.checked) {
                var memberDetails = {};
                memberDetails.VendorId = document.getElementById("VendorId").value;
                memberDetails.PONumber = document.getElementById("PONumber").value;
                memberDetails.POCreatedDate = "2023-02-13";
                memberDetails.ProductId = document.getElementById("Pr_ID_" + i).value;
                memberDetails.ProductName = document.getElementById("Pr_Name_" + i).value;
                memberDetails.ProductQuantity = document.getElementById("count_" + i).value;
                memberDetails.ProductUnitPrice = document.getElementById("UnitPrice_" + i).value;
                memberDetails.ProductTotalPrice = document.getElementById("TAmount_" + i).value;
                alert(memberDetails.VendorId + " " + memberDetails.PONumber + " " + memberDetails.ProductId);
                ListOfOrderProducts.push(memberDetails);
            }
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf=8",
        url: "AddProduct",
        data: JSON.stringify(ListOfOrderProducts),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Hello");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
        
}
```

I tried to create it by using 3 models

```
public class OrderProducts
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PONumber { get; set; }


        public DateTime POCreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string? .....
```

```
public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "PO Number")]
        public string PONumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int VendorId{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Products")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public int TotalProducts { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Items")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Amount")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Paid Amount")].....
```

```
public class POWithOrders
    {
        public string PONumber { get; set; }

        public string VendorId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public List<OrderProducts> ListOfOrderProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

I need help as my Controller (AddProduct) HTTPPOSt didn't get the Data

I provided all details what I have done and what is happening, My controller is not getting the model data, which I am trying to post from view to controller. I don't know what is going on there.

Comment: Could you share  your Product model?

Comment: Do you want to get the data like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA3ej.png  ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending Form Data via AJAX you will also need to add the `[FromBody]` decoration to the PurchaseOrder parameter.

#### Example

```cs
public IActionResult CreatePO([FromBody]PurchaseOrder model)
```

#### Resource

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending-form-data-via-ajax

Comment: I tried it, but still get a null value in Controller.

Comment: PurchaseOrder model received a null in the value, means still unable to get data

Comment: There might more than one problem with this.
Try assigning a value to the date server side, inside the controller rather than via Javascript if this is always going to be hardcoded. Assigning a hard-coded value client-side could lead to different behaviour based on the browser settings.
`memberDetails.POCreatedDate = "2023-02-13";`